# The http://localhost:8080/axis2 link does not work

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache-axis, tomcat8

Hello fellow programmers,

I have to get axis2 (version 1.7.2) working in Tomcat (version 8.0.33) but here I encounter a annoying problem. I have followed the steps in the tutorial (from the axis.apache website) until the point of checking the link mentioned in the topic title. 
I have downloaded the Axis2.war file and placed it in the webapps folder in the tomcat home directory (/opt/tomcat).

When I start tomcat using the startup.sh file and visit the homepage it all seems to work. visiting the link http://localhost:8080/ will show me the text:

**It works !
If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup Tomcat successfully. Congratulations!** etc etc

But then when I visit http://localhost:8080/axis2 I get:

**HTTP Status 404 - /axis2
type Status report
message /axis2
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.28 (Ubuntu)**

When I run the .startup file and at the same time look at my webapps folder I see that the .war folder is extracted and makes the axis2 folder appear, thus it works until there at least.

Does someone has an idea of what could be wrong here?

PS: I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

if your deploy axis2.war, port must be the same at the Apache Tomcat and Axis2 8080, check file tomcat_dir\conf\server.xml

Comment: The ports are at 8080. but somehow it still won't work.